# R преобразование таблицы

Tags: r, таблицы

Имеется такая вот таблица.
Она состоит из трёх столбцов
Необходимо сделать элементы одного столбца строками, элементы второго столбцами, а элементы третьего расставить на пересечения, в соответствии с изначальной таблицей.
[image: Изначальная таблица]

опыта в написании скриптов на R у меня мало, долго уже сижу над этим, помогите, пожалуйста)

Comment: никаких «скриптов» писать не надо. всё уже давно написано и опакетировано. надо читать. например, про `stats::reshape()`, или `tidyr::spread()` или ещё множество других вариантов: `reshape2::cast()`, `spreadsheets::unpivot()`, `databases::unfold()` …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

никаких «скриптов» писать не надо. всё уже давно написано и опакетировано. надо читать. например, про `stats::reshape()`, или `tidyr::spread()` или ещё множество других вариантов: `reshape2::cast()`, `spreadsheets::unpivot()`, `databases::unfold()` …

---

например:

```
> tidyr::spread(d, y, z)
#   x a b
# 1 1 5 6
# 2 2 7 8
```

где:

```
> d
#   x y z
# 1 1 a 5
# 2 1 b 6
# 3 2 a 7
# 4 2 b 8
```

Comment: Я забыл уточнить, что данные в столбцах дублируются, но целых две минуты гугления решили  эту проблему.
нужно было дополнительно применить команду dplyr::count().
спасибо Вам за ответ !